# params keyword taking an array as a single parameter interprets the contents of the array as all its parameters

Tags: c#, arrays, parameters

I have written a simple program using the `params` keyword to take parameters and write them to the console.  What I want/expect to happen, and what the [C# documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) will happen when I pass a single array to the parameter with the `params` tag is that the array will become the first element in the `params` array.  Here is some sample code:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        Paramtest(new object[] { "hi", "wow", 78 });
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void Paramtest(params object[] args) {
        foreach (object o in args) {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} is a type of {1}.", o.ToString(), o.GetType());
        }
    }
```

What I **should** see is one line of writing on the console that states:

```
System.object[] is a type of System.object[].
```

What I **do** see is three lines of writing:

```
hi is a type of System.String.
wow is a type of System.String.
78 is a type of System.Int32.
```

I've discovered that calling `Paramtest` with another parameter after the array, like this: `Paramtest(new object[] { "hi", "wow", 78 }, String.Empty);`, produces the intended results (plus the empty string), so that might be one way to work around this problem, however it isn't elegant or a good idea in my case.  From what the documentation says, this shouldn't be happening.  Is there any  **elegant** workaround for this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# params apparent compiler bug (C# 5.0)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9709642/c-sharp-params-apparent-compiler-bug-c-5-0)

Comment: Yes, I think it is :(
Unfortunately, I did not see that post when doing my research before posting my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cast the argument to an `object`:

```
public static void Main()
{
    Paramtest((object)new object[] { "hi", "wow", 78 });
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I agree that the sample code you pointed to in the documentation can lead to a bit of confusion. Here you are using **Object array** whereas the example used an **Integer array**, which is handled differently.

Look at this answer to understand whats going on: [C# params object[] strange behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876463/c-sharp-params-object-strange-behavior/35876845)