# Why string[] is interpreted as object[], not as object, but we can assign object obj = new string[]?

Tags: c#, arrays, object, reflection

I currently am learning about `Reflection` late binding from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s0eIgl5iqqQ&index=55&list=PLAC325451207E3105).

And as I replicate the code in the video, there was one part which puzzles me. It is when `Invoke` method is used:

```
MethodInfo getFullNameMethod = customerType.GetMethod("GetFullName");
string[] parameters = new string[2];
parameters[0] = "First";
parameters[1] = "Last";

//here is where I got confused...
string fullName = (string)getFullNameMethod.Invoke(customerInstance, parameters);
```

As far as I can see (also shown in the video) `Invoke` has input parameters of `(object, object[])` and has no overloaded method with input parameters `(object, object)`.

What being passed here are `(object, string[])`. And so, at first I expected that there would be compilation error as I thought `string[]` is an `object` rather than `object[]`. But.... there is no compilation error.

That puzzles me: why `string[]` is an `object[]` rather than `object` (every `Type` is C# is derived from `object` after all)? Can we not assign `string[]` as an `object` like this?

```
object obj = new string[3]; //this is OK
```

How can a `string[]` is both `object` and `object[]`? Using other data type, say `int`, as an analogy, I will never expect a variable as `int` and `int[]` at the same time.

Can somebody enlighten me?

---

```
Here is my full code:

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication2 {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            Assembly executingAssembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
            Type customerType = executingAssembly.GetType("ConsoleApplication2.Customer");
            object customerInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(customerType);
            MethodInfo getFullNameMethod = customerType.GetMethod("GetFullName");
            string[] parameters = new string[2];
            parameters[0] = "First";
            parameters[1] = "Last";
            string fullName = (string)getFullNameMethod.Invoke(customerInstance, parameters);
            Console.WriteLine(fullName);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class Customer {
        public string GetFullName(string FirstName, string LastName) {
            return FirstName + " " + LastName;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: First, every `class` and `struct` in .NET (including every array) ultimately derives from `object`, so `string[]` can be converted to `object`. Second, for compatibility with Java, arrays in .NET are "covariant", meaning that an array of type X can be converted to an array of type Y if X has a reference conversion to Y. Because `string` derives from `object`, `string[]` can be converted to `object[]`.

Comment: @MichaelLiu that should be the answer! :) could you just explain a little bit more about "for compatibility with Java, arrays in .NET are covariant"? Because I am not too familiar with Java..

Comment: Eric Lippert has a brief blog post that talks about it: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance/

Comment: @MichaelLiu OK, will look at that. Thanks again.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35876463/c-sharp-params-object-strange-behavior/35876845#35876845 from yesterday, and numerous questions before that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to section 12.5 in [`MSDN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664572(v=vs.71).aspx)

> For any two reference-types A and B, if an implicit reference
>   conversion (Section 6.1.4) or explicit reference conversion (Section
>   6.2.3) exists from A to B, then the same reference conversion also exists from the array type A[R] to the array type B[R], where R is any
>   given rank-specifier (but the same for both array types). *This
>   relationship is known as array covariance*.

Below code is perfectly valid.

```
string[] items = new string[] {"A", "B", "C"};      
object[] objItems = items;
```

That's why in your case, passing `string[]` is valid and will be converted to `object[]`

Comment: Thanks, that explains. :)

Comment: @Ian my pleasure :-)