# Replace substrings with values from array

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have a string like this:

```
string source = hello{1}from{2}my{3}world
```

And an array like this:

```
var valArray = new[] { "Val0", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };
```

I want to replace "{index}" substring with appropriate values from array.

I've already written the code, but it looks ugly

```
var valArray = new[] { "Val0", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };
var source = "hello{1}from{2}my{3}world";
var substr = source;
string pattern = $"{Regex.Escape(start)}{".+?"}{Regex.Escape(end)}";

foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(source, pattern))
{
    var value = m.Groups[0].Value;
    var ind = Convert.ToInt32(m.Groups[0].Value.TrimStart(start.ToCharArray()).TrimEnd(end.ToCharArray()));
    substr = substr.Replace(value, valArray[ind]);
}
return substr;
```

Any tips how to get this solved?

Thanks!

Comment: Result string must be like this: "helloVal1fromVal2myVal3world"

Comment: if you source will be `hello{2}from{1}my{3}world` and `var valArray = new[] { "Val0", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };` what should be the output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Regex.Replace(string input, string pattern, MatchEvaluator evaluator)`

```
var valArray = new[] { "Val0", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };
var source = "hello{1}from{2}my{3}world";

string result = Regex.Replace(
    source,
    "{(?<index>\\d+)}",
    match => valArray[int.Parse(match.Groups["index"].Value)]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [`String.Format`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1csw23d(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
string result = string.Format(source, valArray); // "helloVal1fromVal2myVal3world"
```

Just keep in mind that it's indexing from 0, not from 1.

Comment: No code must automatic find and adjust all indexes
{valArray} to valArray[index]

Comment: Add `valArray.Cast<object>().ToArray()`, `valArray` will be treated as an obejct, not as array of objects to be passed as `params`.

Comment: @IvanGritsenko that isn't true `string.Format("hello{1}from{2}my{3}world", valArray);` gives `helloVal1fromVal2myVal3world` just fine

Comment: @weston Yep, you're right. I just looked at Ivan's comment and thought "yeah, that makes sense". Now I properly tested it - an array of strings works just fine.

Comment: @weston, Surprisely it is [not working](https://ideone.com/8oQt4G) on `int[]` or any other struct array.

Comment: This is because of [array covariance](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35876845/1770952) for reference types.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Test]
public void SO_36103066()
{
    string[] valArray = new[] { "Val0", "Val1", "Val2", "Val3" };
    //prefix array with another value so works from index {1}
    string[] parameters = new string[1] { null }.Concat(valArray).ToArray(); 
    string result = string.Format("hello{1}from{2}my{3}world", parameters);
    Assert.AreEqual("helloVal0fromVal1myVal2world", result);
}
```